# My laptop repeatedly goes to a black screen requiring restart

Tags: windows-7, laptop, mouse, dell-latitude

Every 5-10 minutes, my Dell Latitude E5430 laptop goes to a black screen.  I wiggle the mouse, but it doesn't turn on, so I  have to shut everything down and restart.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is a common screen problem on older Dell laptops. I had the same problem on my Latitude E5000.
The screen goes too dim, almost invisible and then you need to restart your Laptop to have things fixed.

What causes it is probably the screen inverter and the only fix is to change it.

However, I had figured a way to cope with this problem myself.

First of all, every time this happened, I removed its battery and    power cord for some seconds.

Secondly, I operated it without having    the battery plugged in, just the power cord. However, This may be a    problem for anyone who wants to use it as a Laptop and not as a    stable PC.

Last but most important, do not touch or shake the screen    at all while the Laptop is on, as it could cause problems, this had    happened to me many times.

Nevertheless, the best solution is changing the inverter. If you search for an inverter for your Laptop model on Google, you can find many cheap ones.